# Is it possible to add a variable's value to an element's class?

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

I would like to add the class "pl1" or "pl2" to a div that was created through Javascript. If currPlayer = 1, then the div would have the class "pl1" and if currPlayer = 2, the div's class would be "pl2". Is this possible? If so, when the currPlayer variable changes its value, will that change the class of the Div I created? My code attempts are below. Thanks in advance!

```js
let currPlayer = 1;
let piece = document.createElement("div");
piece.setAttribute("id", `pl${currPlayer}`)


piece.classList.add("pl${currPlayer}");
```

Comment: The error I get for the setAttribute function attempt is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'currPlayer' has already been declared

Comment: *Is this possible?* Yes. *when the currPlayer variable changes its value, will that change the class of the Div I created* No.

Comment: Your first code attempt is setting the `id` attribute.  The second is not using the correct string delimiters for interpolation

Comment: If you `classList.add(...)`, the existing class(es) will be retained. If you set the `className` property or the `"class"` attribute, you will overwrite any existing classes.

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that I was using "id", the class now shows as pl1! However, I am still receiving the error message.

Comment: @BerkleyOlmstead Well, what is unclear about that error? The error message clearly tells you what the problem is.